# failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive using int-sftp:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I was able to login into SFTP location using a Bitvise SFTP access client tool with just `userid` and `pswd`. 
So, I am trying to use `int-sftp:outbound-gateway`  and access an SFTP location by using the `userid` and `pswd` but not with any key file and getting the below error.  My question is : Can we access the SFTP location only with ID, Pswd thru an application?

```
WARNING: failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
Throwable occurred: org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.sftp.gateway.SftpOutboundGateway#0]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:361)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:315)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:204)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:323)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:286)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:277)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at $Proxy10.lsGetAndRmFiles(Unknown Source)
    at com.farmers.csi.batchutil.service.CopyOfSchedulerServiceImplDup.main(CopyOfSchedulerServiceImplDup.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:293)
```

Comment: Try to switch on `log4j.category.com.jcraft.jsch=DEBUG` and take a look to the logs after the error.